# Merge two tables and find overlapping dates and Gaps

Tags: sql, oracle, overlapping

I would like to solve below scenarios for ID 100 & 101 as given output using oracle Analytical functions. any ideas?

TABLE A:

```
ID   ValidFrom   ValidTo
100  1/1/2009    12/31/2010
100  1/1/2011    3/31/2012
101  8/1/2013    7/31/2014
101  8/1/2014    8/31/2014
```

TABLE B

```
ID   ValidFrom   ValidTo
100  11/1/2008   12/31/2011
100  2/1/2012    2/29/2012
101  8/1/2013    6/30/2014
101  7/1/2014    8/31/2014
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID   ValidFrom   ValidTo
100  11/1/2008  12/31/2008
100  1/1/2009   12/31/2010
100  1/1/2011   12/31/2011
100  1/1/2012   1/31/2012
100  2/1/2012   2/29/2012
100  3/1/2012   3/31/2012
---------------------------
101  8/1/2013   6/30/2014
101  7/1/2014   7/31/2014
101  8/1/2014   8/31/2014
```

Comment: Please explain the logic.  It is not obvious.  The logic is clearly neither "both are valid" or "either one is valid".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query, using analytic `lead()` does the job. Column `note` shows if row comes from your data or if it is missing gap:

```
select id, d1, d2, case dir when 3 then 'GAP' end note 
  from (
    select id, 
           case when dir = 2 
                 and lead(dir) over (partition by id order by dt) = 1
                 and lead(dt) over (partition by id order by dt) <> dt + 1
                then dt + 1 
                else dt
           end d1,
           case when dir = 2 
                 and lead(dir) over (partition by id order by dt) = 1
                 and lead(dt) over (partition by id order by dt) <> dt + 1
                then 3 
                else dir
           end dir,
           case when lead(dir) over (partition by id order by dt) = 1 
                then lead(dt)  over (partition by id order by dt) - 1
                else lead(dt)  over (partition by id order by dt) 
            end d2
      from (
        select * from a unpivot (dt for dir in (validfrom as 1, validto as 2)) union 
        select * from b unpivot (dt for dir in (validfrom as 1, validto as 2)) ) )
  where dir in (1, 3)
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ed785b9091271ae827f8dabccb981cf)</sup>**

At first data is unpivoted just to have all dates in one column, it's easier for further analytics. Union removes duplicated values. Column `dir` informs if this is `from` or `to` date. Then `lead` logic is applied, depending on type of this direction. I think it can be simplified somewhat :)