# Merge two table based on date and key fields

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join

I have two table with version_start and version_end date. I want to merge those tables as shown in below sample.

Table 1

```
VERSION_START_DT    VERSION_END_DT  KEY ATTR1   
6/2/2020            6/16/2020       123  A  
6/17/2020           12/31/2022      123  B
```

Table 2

```
VERSION_START_DT    VERSION_END_DT  KEY ATTR2   
6/11/2020           12/31/2023      123  C
```

Output should be non overlapping versions date with their corresponding attribute's value

```
VERSION_START_DT    VERSION_END_DT  KEY ATTR1   ATTR2
6/2/2020            6/10/2020       123   A     NULL
6/11/2020           6/16/2020       123   A     C
6/17/2020           12/31/2022      123   B     C
01/01/2023          12/31/2023      123   NULL  C
```

Comment: mysql or oracle? Pick one!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I answered recently on [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498407/merge-two-tables-and-find-overlapping-dates-and-gaps/62500455#62500455). Here you do not need gaps filled, but you want attributes from both tables. It was for Oracle. Please specify if you are using MySQLor Oracle.

Comment: In case it's Oracle [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6921c887377f6fbc4ca0ecab7042a60c) should help.

Answer (score 0):

plz try something like this

```
SELECT version_start.VERSION_START_DT , version_end.VERSION_END_DT, version_start.KEY
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN version_end ON version_start.ATTR1=version_end.ATTR2;
```

tuturial  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

or  this    plz copy paste the geenral query    the edit the query by yr need

SELECT version_start.VERSION_START_DT, version_end.VERSION_END_DT
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN version_end ON version_start.VERSION_START_DT = version_end.VERSION_END_DT;

u can try something like this

Comment: SELECT version_start.VERSION_START_DT , version_end.VERSION_END_DT, version_start.KEY FROM version_start INNER JOIN version_end ON version_start.ATTR1=version_end.ATTR2;

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what it's doing and why.

Comment: But in general, we avoid answering questions that ask for us to write basic code for them. They're supposed to try to solve the problem themselves, then we help them fix it.

Comment: Ok sure    but i had sent ti him the tuturial    basic join is that   and when we wants to join 2 or more table we can connect the column of the tables and call one or more to a a task

Comment: the tuturial is apparently clarify

Comment: only connection betwwen columns and then call it

Comment: Don't put code in comments. If you need to correct the answer, click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62518860/edit) link.

Comment: some thing like this      for the first time detect what u need from a column then  u can make the query by u nned   even u dont need remmeber the code only copy paste the code to teh note pad and Fake it until u make it

Comment: Put the explanation in the answer, not comments.